# How to generate a pdf from a template with Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to generate a PDF from my template which has data generated from some calculations
and operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/

if you need more docs look here:
http://www.reportlab.com/

If your goal is to ouput the html itself into the PDF, you are probably going to run into major issues. templating a PDF with reportlab is very different from HTML/CSS

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you might want to just use wkhtmltopdf ( http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ ) - or similar - to convert web pages into PDF, because HTML templates are easy. On the other hand, reportlab is the only lib that will allow you to generate PDFs in python ( AFAIK ), and it's super boring and outdated. To be fair, the paid version of reportlab is hopefully better.

Answer (score 1):

Based on experience I'd say that best way to render PDFs is to render a latex template to a file and then Popen `pdfTeX` or whatever else  you like.

Comment: Can't believe how much time I wasted trying to render printable pages without trying this option

Comment: @seler: what library does this?